# Unbound variable error in slimv with mit-scheme

Tags: mit-scheme, slimv

After trying to start swank server from vim (or after executing the command

scheme --load /usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/slime/contrib/swank-mit-scheme.scm

from terminal prompt) I get the following error:

```
Image saved on Tuesday November 8, 2011 at 10:40:30 PM
  Release 9.1.1 || Microcode 15.3  || Runtime 15.7 
  SF 4.41       || LIAR/i386 4.118 || Edwin 3.116

;Loading "/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/slime/contrib/swank-mit-scheme.scm"...
;Unbound variable: o
;To continue, call RESTART with an option number:
; (RESTART 3) => Specify a value to use instead of o.
; (RESTART 2) => Define o to a given value.
; (RESTART 1) => Return to read-eval-print level 1.
```

It seems that the error is caused by the line:

```
(define-generic inspect (o))
```

Any ideas what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Try to run swank-mit-scheme.scm embedded in Slimv. It is slightly modified: it loads options and runs swank server in an infinite loop.

Comment: I installed slimv097.zip from www.vim.org. It stops with error:
   
    `;netcat: "4005: inverse host lookup failed: "`
    
which seems to be discussed (unfortunately without solution) in
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9146935/how-to-start-repl-for-slimv-with-mit-scheme

I can't get the swank.log file: I tried to set `g:swank_log=1` in my .vimrc file and also `log=True` in swank.py but no swank.log was generated.

Comment: If you have a `swank-mit-scheme.scm` that is compatible with your `netcat` then add `(load-option format)` and `(load-option sos)` at the beginning. Also call the swank server in an infinite loop at the end. Check what lines have been added to the Slimv version. You can also try to modify the `netcat` call if it accepts different arguments on your system.

Comment: So I used `swank-mit-scheme.scm` from my distribution and applied described changes. After defining yet `swank:swank-require` to return `nil` it works now. Thank you.